# Why im getting ,the number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K ERROR. Aftter updating dexguard version to 8.3.03?

Tags: android, dex, dexguard

Recently i updated dexguard version to 8.0.03.The documentation says that you will not need to add  `multiDexEnabled true` in app level gradle file.
 If i do so,project sync fails with error
**Found incompatible settings for variants configured with DexGuard.**
If i remove `multiDexEnabled true` from the gradle,project syncs successfully but when i run application, build fails with following error
**The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.**
 For the `dex` i have created application class extending `MultidexApplication` and declared it in `AndroidManifest`.But still getting the `64K`error.
Please help
Cheers

Comment: you likely need `multiDexEnabled true` in gradle. Post more datails on which `Found incompatible settings for variants configured with DexGuard.` exactly.

Comment: DexGuard is incompatible with the setting multiDexEnabled true, if you need multidex support for your application, add -multidex to your configuration.

Comment: btw. the documentation clearly states that multiDexEnabled is not supported and you have to disable this setting for build types using Dexguard.

Comment: @T.Neidhart Thanks for the comment.Can you please tell how to add -multidex in configuration.

Comment: Usually using a text editor works.